# Importing *.pdf_tex file error

Tags: pdf, compiler-errors, latex, graphic, pdftex

I have made a graphic with inkscape. Now I'm trying to build it in Latex. I' m working with TEXMaker. Therefore I have exported my graphic as `*.pdf_tex` and `*.pdf`. 
In macros i have added the following

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{fileWithPictures/}}
```

my picture is build in like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\def\svgwidth{175pt}
\input{fileWithPictures/pic.pdf_tex}
%\includegraphics[width=2in]{fileWithPictures/pic.pdf_tex}

\end{figure}
```

Here I'm getting the following error. "!Package pdftex.def Error: File'pic.pdf" not found. See the pdftex.def package.."

I have tryed also to work with includegraphics which not succed. Because there he it doesn't recognize `pdf_tex` format.

Interesting is that the compiler says that there is not a file called "`pic.pdf`" and not "`pic.pdf_tex`". Althought both files are clearly in the file. To be sure i put the `pic.svg` file in the file. Now i have no more ideas and would be happy to get some help

Thanks

Comment: Your reference to "file" here seems ambiguous. Is `pic.pdf` and `pic.pdf_tex` inside a *folder* called `fileWithPictures/`? If this is the case and you're still having problems, what about putting them in the same folder as the main document? Relevant reference: [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099/5764)

Comment: yes, you right. I have change it and now i it's in my document.

Comment: now i have to more problems. 1. it is not in the right place in the document. 2. the text parts are not on the right place in the picture. Do You have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use `resizebox` to set the `width` of your file instead of `\def\svgwidth{175pt}` it will solve your problem

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \input{fileWithPictures/pic.pdf_tex}
}
```